FCM message not shown when app is closed in release mode
I have used FCM along with Flutter local notification for receiving messages. Flutter local notifiation is used to show notification when app is in foreground.
When I terminate the application and send a message from Firebase Console, the below message appears in the logcat.

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/dart_runtime_hooks.cc(38)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:x/x/x/data/firebase_api.dart' not found.
E/flutter ( 9510): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(117)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:x/x/x/data/firebase_api.dart' not found.
E/flutter ( 9510): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(117)] Dart Error: Dart_LookupLibrary: library 'package:x/x/x/data/firebase_api.dart' not found.

This is my class:
class FirebaseAPI {
    final _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
    final _localNotification = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    
    // Notification channel (Android only)
    final AndroidNotificationChannel _androidNotificationChannel = const AndroidNotificationChannel(
      'high_importance_channel',
      'High Importance Notifications',
      description: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    
    FirebaseAPI() {
      // Initialize Firebase Messaging and Local Notification
      initNotification();
    }
    
    // Background message handler (needs to be a top-level function)
    static Future<void> handleBackgroundMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('Background Message Received: payload ${message.data}');
    
      // Extract title and body from the data payload
      String title = message.data['title_en'] ?? 'Default Title';
      String body = message.data['body_en'] ?? 'Default Body';
    
      final localNotifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
      await localNotifications.show(
        message.notification?.hashCode ?? 0,
        title,
        body,    
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(    
            'high_importance_channel',
            'High Importance Notifications',
            channelDescription: 'This channel is used for important notifications.',
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
            icon: '@mipmap/aa', // Ensure this icon exists in your resources
          ),
        ),
        payload: jsonEncode(message.data),
      );
    }
    
    // Listen to messages when the app is closed
    
    // Foreground message handler
    Future<void> handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
      print('Foreground Message Received: payload ${message.data}');
    
      // Extract title and body from the data payload
      String title = message.data['title_en'] ?? 'Default Title';
      String body = message.data['body_en'] ?? 'Default Body';
    
      await _showLocalNotification(title, body);
    }
    
    // Show local notification function
    Future<void> _showLocalNotification(String title, String body) async {
      await _localNotification.show(
        DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000, // Unique ID
        title,
        body,
        NotificationDetails(
          android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
            _androidNotificationChannel.id,
            _androidNotificationChannel.name,
            channelDescription: _androidNotificationChannel.description,
            importance: Importance.high,
            priority: Priority.high,
            icon: '@mipmap/aa', // Ensure this icon exists in your resources
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    
    // Initialize local notification settings
    Future<void> initLocalNotification() async {
      const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitSettings = AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
      const InitializationSettings initSettings = InitializationSettings(android: androidInitSettings);
    
      await _localNotification.initialize(initSettings);
      await _localNotification
          .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
          ?.createNotificationChannel(_androidNotificationChannel);
    }
    
    // Initialize push notifications with Firebase
    Future<void> initPushNotification() async {
      // Set foreground notification presentation options for iOS (if applicable)
      await _firebaseMessaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
        alert: true,
        badge: true,
        sound: true,
      );
    
      // Set up background message handler
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(handleBackgroundMessage);
    
      // Listen to messages when the app is in the foreground
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(handleMessage);    
      // Listen to messages that open the app when tapped
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(handleMessage);
    }
    
    // Complete notification initialization
    Future<void> initNotification() async {
      // Request notification permissions
      await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission();
    
      // Get the device token (optional)
      String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("Device Token: $token");
    
      // Initialize local and push notifications
      await initLocalNotification();
      await initPushNotification();
    }
    
    // Retrieve device token (for sending notifications via server)    
    Future<String?> getDeviceToken() async {    
      String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();    
      return token;    
    }
}

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this problem?
